# Copy Wordpress to new directory

Tags: database, installation, backup

I have a wordpress site up and running on mydomain.com/wordpress1/

When I create a new installation of wordpress on mydomain.com/wordpress2/ it starts up and runs fine, creating a brand new database (databasedefault). However, I have copied wordpress1s database (database1) into a new database (database2).

Everything is still working in mydomain.com/wordpress1/, but when I change config.php for mydomain.com/wordpress2/ to connect it to database2, I go to mydomain.com/wordpress2/and the site fails to load.

If I reconnect mydomain.com/wordpress2/ to databasedefault, everything works fine again.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- Check your database for wp_options table, site_url and home_url should point to new installation.
- Refresh your permalinks
- Check Settings -> Readings to check if home page is set